# perl ftp not working

Tags: perl

Script works fine, but ftp code uploading the xls but uploading with 0 byte, but if ftp  code present in before of the following snippet, FTP Works Fine,

What is the error in code,

`my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('TestRPT.xls');`
`my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet('TestRPT Report');`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use POSIX qw(strftime);


my $CurTimeStamp=time;
my $LastSunTimestamp=($CurTimeStamp - 168*60*60);
my $row;
my $PinNumber;
my $PinAmount;
my $get_date;
my $get_time;
my $get_time_stamp;
my $DoFTPFlg = "yes";


# Create a new workbook and add a worksheet.
my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('TestRPT.xls');
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet('TestRPT Report');


# Write some text. in write function First Argument for ROW, Second Argument for COLUMN, Third Argument for Title/Text to display
$worksheet->write(0, 0,  'val1');
$worksheet->write(0, 1,  'val2');
$worksheet->write(0, 2,  'val3');
$worksheet->write(0, 3,  'val4');
my $cnt = 1;
    $get_time_stamp = time;
    $get_date = strftime("%m/%d/%y",localtime($get_time_stamp));
    $get_time = strftime("%H:%M",localtime($get_time_stamp));
    # Write some numbers.
    $worksheet->write($cnt, 0,  "val1");          
    $worksheet->write($cnt, 1,  "val2");    
    $worksheet->write($cnt, 2,  "val3"); 
    $worksheet->write($cnt, 3,  "val4"); 




if ($DoFTPFlg eq "yes") {
    print "DO FTP";
    use Net::FTP;
    my $ftp;
    $ftp = Net::FTP->new("mysite.in", Debug => 0);
    $ftp->login("user",'pass');
    $ftp->cwd("/www/");
    $ftp->put("TestRPT.xls");
    $ftp->quit; 

}
```

Comment: my problem fixed, i am not added the $workbook->close(); at the end of place before my ftp code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `close` your `$workbook` object before trying to do anything with the file.

From the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#close%28%29):

> An explicit close() is required if the file must be closed prior to performing some external action on it such as copying it, reading its size or attaching it to an email.

Answer (score 1):

Try a slight modification on your code. Instead of

```
$ftp->put("TestRPT.xls");
```

Create another file in the `www` directory and try to ftp that file. If that file is called `test.txt`, change your line to:

```
$ftp->put("TestRPT.xls");
```

Thus, the only change in your code is the name of the file being FTP'd. If your FTP works, the problem isn't with the FTP, but with the `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` module. As [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat) has already stated, you need to do an explicit `close` on your object.

If your FTP doesn't work, it probably is an issue with the FTP call (although it looks fine to me).